# ODL and Openstack issue

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, opendaylight, openstack-neutron

I am running one controller and one compute node. Controller node is running both ODL and OpenStack. I created tenants, underthem i created networks and launched instances on them. All is see on ODL web GUI is 3 swithces, and I guess those are br-int and br-ex of controller and br-int of compute and the links are missing too. Is there anyway where I can see my whole OpenStack topology on ODL GUI with the links?

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to see all the ovs-bridges used in openstack and all the VMs attached to it. Well you can definitely see that.Just ping all the VMs from one VM just to make sure flows are added with MAC address of VMs on OVS by controller and then you will see the topology on the GUI.